# Anchor tag onclick to call a code behind method

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="orgvalid();return false;" class="regular">Register</a>` in my aspx page. Once true is returned from the function `orgvalid()` I want to call a code behind function, `insertorganization()`. Is it possible to do so? If so, how?

Comment: accept some answers from your previous questions please

Comment: href = what? That's just nasty. You should probably read http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/

Comment: is orgvalid() function is in javascript(client side) and insertorganization() is in c# (server side).. is that you mean...??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="insertOrganization();return false;" class="regular">Register</a>
```

InserOrganization Function:

```
function InsertOrganization(){
  if(orgvalid()){
     //do your thing here
  }
  else
    alert("not valid");
}

function orgvalid(){
  if({condition for true})
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) instead:

```
  <asp:LinkButton id="RegisterButton"
   Text="Register"
   OnClientClick="return orgvalid();"
   OnClick="Register_Click"
   runat="server" />
```

and in the Register_Click server function you could call the `insertorganization` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a LinkButton instead

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="somecommandname" 
runat="server" OnCommand="insertorganization" 
CommandArgument="some praram">
Register
</asp:LinkButton>
```

To note that this will perform a postback.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="?i=1" id ="a" runat = "server">

on Page_load()
if (Request.QueryString["i"] == "1")
{
//call ur code here
AreaFootPrint_Click(null,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (orgvalid()) { insertorganisation(); } return false;
```